# Ruby on Rails: Mass-Assignment on iteration in loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

I'm getting mass-assignment error.

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

These numbers represent the iteration in this loop:

```
<% (1..7).each do |i| %>
  <%= select_tag "hour[#{i}][day]", options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<% end %>
```

This is in my model:

```
attr_accessible :day, :open_time, :close_time
```

I'm trying to create an array like this:

```
"hour"=>{
 "1"=>{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6","close_time"=>"6"},
 "2"=>{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6","close_time"=>"6"},
 "3"=>{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6","close_time"=>"6"}
}
```

And I'm trying to save each iteration in a new row into the database

```
def create
  @hour = @hourable.hours.new(params[:hour])
end
```

How do I fix the iteration mass-assignment? or am I doing this all wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what you want the application to do. It is hard to tell from your code. What is the class? What are the user setting with the select_tag?

Comment: "I'm trying to create an array like this:" that's a hash, which is probably part of your problem, the array would look like this: `hours = [{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"}, {"day"=>"Monday","open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"},{"day"=>"Tuesday","open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"}]`

Comment: @Isotope makes sense. Do you think you can help me get it where I don't need the numbers? I tried removing the `#{i}`, and just have something like `hour[day]`, I get an `Internal Server Error` with this message: `expected Array (got String) for param `day'`

Comment: @andrewliu: Please put an update for your question detailing the requirement. May be the whole view content you can provide and how you want to display the select tag, its values,  and how you want to save it in database, what are values `:open_time`, `:close_time` etc.

Comment: `<%= select_tag "hour[i][open_time]", options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<%= select_tag "hour[i][close_time]", options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "hour[i][day]", value: i %>` then you just need to turn the day int into a string

Comment: @Isotope thanks for helping me! When I change `#{i}` to just `[i]`, it stays `[i]` in HTML, and when I try to submit the form I get this: `"hour"=>{"i"=>{"day"=>"Sunday",
 "open_time"=>"6",
 "close_time"=>"6"},
 "day"=>["Sunday",
 "Sunday"]},
 "commit"=>"Create Hour", ...` It doesn't have multiple values, just one group under `[i]`

Comment: yep, sorry the `i` should have been escaped. This would be so much easier with `fields_for` or `nested_form`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the hash, Active Record assumes that '1', '2' and '3' are column names OR attributes of the Model and as you have not specified `attr_accessible` option for the accessing columns, it is throwing `mass-assignment error`. Otherwise you need to create a hash as follows:

```
"hour"=>{
"day"=>"Sunday",
"open_time"=>"6",
"close_time"=>"6"}
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Makes sense. I was wondering if you can help me expand my original question. How do I do it so my array becomes like this? If I remove the `#{i}` from the bracket and make it like `"hour[day][]"`, all the values will go into one array and it doesn't split like what @Isotope mentioned in the comment above. Like this `hours = [{"day"=>["Sunday","Monday",Tuesday"]...` etc etc...

Comment: I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272276/ruby-on-rails-receiving-internal-server-error-expected-array-in-my-form-with-a

Answer (score 1):

Your hour attributes is

```
"hour" => {
 "1"=>{"day"=>"Sunday", "open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"},
 "2"=>{"day"=>"Sunday", "open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"},
 "3"=>{"day"=>"Sunday", "open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"}
}
```

Which means, your hours table should have attributes 1, 2 and 3.