# Ruby on Rails receiving Internal Server Error: expected Array (got String) for param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a loop in a form and I'm trying to create multiple data with same name but I'm getting an error with my syntax.

I had another question to the same application [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263538/ruby-on-rails-mass-assignment-on-iteration-in-loop?noredirect=1#comment35602679_23263538) where I had a mass-assignment error because of the numbers in the array

```
<%= form_for [@hourable, @hour] do |f| %>

<% (1..7).each do |i| %>
  <%= select_tag "hour[#{i}][day]", options_for_select(days_hours) %>
  <%= select_tag "hour[#{i}][open_time]", options_for_select([ ... %>
  <%= select_tag "hour[#{i}][open_time]", options_for_select([ ... %>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Which is coming from `[#{i}]`. So I tried removing this, because I thought it would give me this array:

```
"hours" = 
[{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"}, 
{"day"=>"Monday","open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"},
{"day"=>"Tuesday","open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"}]
```

Originally I had this:

```
"hour"=>{
 "1"=>{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6","close_time"=>"6"},
 "2"=>{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6","close_time"=>"6"},
 "3"=>{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6","close_time"=>"6"}
}
```

How do I get to the correct array?

Thanks!

Edit:

Controller:

```
class HoursController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_hourable
  def new
    @hour = @hourable.hours.new
  end
  def create
    @hour = @hourable.hours.new(params[:hour])
  end

  private
  def get_hourable
    @hourable = params[:hourable].camelize.constantize.find_by_user_id(current_user)
  end

  def hourable_id
    params[(params[:hourable].singularize + "_id").to_sym]
  end
end
```

day_hours in my helper

```
def days_hours
[
  ['Sunday', 'Sunday'],
  ['Monday', 'Monday'],
  ['Tuesday', 'Tuesday'],
  ['Wednesday', 'Wednesday'],
  ['Thursday', 'Thursday'],
  ['Friday', 'Friday'],
  ['Saturday', 'Saturday']
]
end
```

This is my model:

```
class Hour < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :day, :open_time, :close_time, :days_attributes
  include IceCube
  belongs_to :hourable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :professional

  serialize :schedule, Hash
  serialize :hour, Hash

end
```

Comment: Is your aim to get a correct array?

Comment: @RajeshCO yes please. I tried deleting the iteration thinking it'll work but I'm getting the error

Comment: what is the value for days_hours? Show the contents of controller also.

Comment: @RajeshCO I updated my post with controller, what do you mean days_hours? I can't find out what the value I get with "hour[day]" because I get an internal server error. I also updated what my form looks like

Comment: `days_hours` in `<%= select_tag "hour[#{i}][day]", options_for_select(days_hours) %>`. Actually the `options_for_select` is used for populating option values in a select tag. Please post the Model also.

Comment: @rajeshco I edited my answer, hopefully this will give a clearer understanding of my application, thanks for your help!

Comment: So in one POST request, you need to get `"hours" = 
[{"day"=>"Sunday","open_time"=>"6", "close_time"=>"6"}]`, right? as per the code you have given, I think you will get 7*3=21 select tags in your HTML code? Is that correct?

Comment: @RajeshCO So right now my database has columns `day`, `close_time`, `open_time`. So essentially I would like it to have multiple input fields so when I click on submit, each group of values will go into the database. That's why originally I had set the numbers in my previous post, because I wanted to upload multiple hours/days into my database, does that make sense?

Comment: please include full backtrace

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for [@hourable, @hour] do |f| %>

  <% 7.times do %>
    <%= select_tag "hour[][day]", options_for_select(days_hours) %>
    <%= select_tag "hour[][open_time]", options_for_select([ ... %>
    <%= select_tag "hour[][close_time]", options_for_select([ ... %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Starting with `hour[]` generates an array within params[:hour].  Each element in the array will have the keys after `hour[]` - in this case, `:day`, `:open_time`, and `:close_time`.

Comment: With this method, I get this error: `Internal Server Error`: 

`expected Hash (got Array) for param 'hour'`

Comment: That's a good sign - raise params or put in `binding.pry` and you'll see you're getting the Array you want.  Now you have to assign the values properly in the controller.  You're only creating one object and assigning `params[:hour]` to it.  That won't work, because it's an array of hashes.  Here's what you need: `@hourable.hours << params[:hour].map { |hour_attrs| Hour.create(hour_attrs) }`

Comment: To clarify: you want to create 7 Hour objects, right?  Your controller only creates one.  The line of code I wrote will give you one Hour object for each set of `:day`, `:open_time`, and `:close_time` the user inputs.  Of course, you will want to make sure that if the user didn't fill in all lines, it's still handled properly... but that's the next step.

Comment: I tried and replaced `@hour = @hourabl.hours.new(params[:hour])` with `@hourable.hours << params[:hour].map { |hour_attrs| Hour.create(hour_attrs) }` but still getting the same error. I'm only doing a loop of up to 7 Hour objects because there's 7 days in a week, but eventually I want it dynamic where users can put more than 1 set of hours in 1 day, so it eventually it'll be more than 7 Hour objects.

Comment: Can you look at the params and tell me what you're getting now?  Maybe that will help us see where the error is creeping in.

Comment: So I redid my form and added field_for instead